# What is the meaning of "The egg I made them shows how much"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "The egg I made them shows how much" in the sentence, 
"I love my MAMI and PAPI. The egg I made them shows how much" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"MAMI" and "PAPI" can be assumed to be variants of "mama" and "papa",

There are a few words that have been left out. Leaving out optional parts of a sentence is called ellipsis.

> "The egg [that] I made [for] them shows how much [I love them]"

A child made their parents an egg, perhaps as an Easter gift.

The verb "make" can take two objects, rather like the verb "give"

> He gave his mother a card
>   He made his mother a card.

When using a relative clause, the object comes to the front, compare:

> He ate a fish -> The fish that he ate...

So

> The card that he gave his mother...
>   The egg that he made his mother...

But when an object is used in such relative clauses, the word "that" can be omitted:

> The card he gave his mother...
>   The egg he made his mother...

Comment: If so, Does "The egg that I made them shows how much I love them" mean "The egg that I made for them shows how much I love them" ? Why is "made them" used instead of "made for them" in this sentence?

Comment: Yes, it means the same as "made for them"

Comment: I've explained further. You should know how objects are used in relative clauses.